# Healpy installation Python 3.4 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2010, python-3.x, healpy

When I try to install Healpy with the command "pyp install healpy" this is the error message:

> File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in
>   query_vcvarsall
>           raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
>       ValueError: ['path']

Before I installed the SDK 7.1 and Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 x64, Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 x86, Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2015 x64, Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2015 x86.

Comment: There is a new healpix library from astropy you may want to check out https://astropy-healpix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

healpy official docs say they dont support windows, see note in [their official docs](https://github.com/healpy/healpy) it says:

> Healpy does not currently support Windows. See: https://github.com/healpy/healpy/issues/25.